# What kind of 16-pin connector is this?

Tags: identification, plug

I was wondering if anyone knew what this type of connector is called.

One of the wires connected to this seems to have a tear, and I'd like to see if I can get a few of these connectors for future use.

The device that this connects to is a third party accessibility Xbox controller, which doesn't seem to be in production anymore. http://lpaccessibletechnologies.com/products/game-controllers/lp-pad
I've reached out to the company to see if they can offer me any support, so far nothing though. Was hoping someone on here might have some idea.

For extra detail, the contacts are more like blades than they are pins, and have a pitch of about 0.8mm/0.0315in

[image: photo of the plug]

Comment: Why not give us context? What is it for?

Comment: Why not give a few context clues such as where you found it, the pitch between pins, etc. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: With no information other than the photo, it looks like the bottom accessory connector for a Motorola Tetra radio (partially disassembled).

Comment: Also looks like it might be a old Nokia phone charger / data cable (the 6680's had something very similar).

Comment: Sorry all, I'll try and add some more details. I was just hoping there was a general name for this connector. It definitely looks like a connector from an old cellphone.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out to be easier, in the end, to just replace the connector on the controller with something more standard.

Comment: Showing the two parts separately rather than mated might also give a better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the connector is from Molex's HandyLink family of connectors. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your response. Seems to be Molex part [043391600](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0453391600/WM6291-ND/2352555)